# How to change IP address from binary to dotted decimal notation?

Tags: java

Can anybody help me ?
I want binary string as input and dotted decimal as output.

Comment: Is the input a string? Or is it four bytes?

Comment: This is something that could be easily found on the web. Ipv4 addresses are four bytes, each byte is an integer. Have you ever wondered why each of the integers in an address range from 0 to 255?

Comment: You should include an input example string and an output example. It seems like all you really needed to know is that there is a `Integer.parseInt(String s, int radix) method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should get an integer from binary (`pareseInt` method) and contact all of them by ".":

```
System.out.println(
        Integer.parseInt("00000011", 2)
                + "."
                + Integer.parseInt("10000000", 2)
                + "."
                + Integer.parseInt("11111111", 2)
                + "."
                + Integer.parseInt("11111111", 2)
);



Output: 3.128.255.255
```

Comment: You appear to have hard coded the binary strings, whereas the OP is getting them as input.

Comment: Where do you see the word "input"?

Comment: The second line of the question body says "Input : IP address:".

Comment: I want to read it from the author. If it's true, I'll add the information. I think that's not true)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't follow. The text mentioning "input" was in the original revision before I edited it. If you don't think there's input into the program, why not just do `System.out.printLn("3.128.255.255");`? I'm downvoting this answer as it's not useful in its current form.

Comment: how to take the binary(32 digit) number notation input from the user to convert it into dotted decimal notation.